# Implementing membership provider using ASP.NET MVC 4 and Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-membership

When we create a new ASP.NET MVC 4 project in Visual Studio 2012, we get option of "Internet application" which implements membership provider.

Is there anything available by which I will use Entity Framework instead of normal ADO.NET while creating new project so that connection to database will be using Entity Framework & not using ADO.NET.

Comment: Entity Framework *uses* ADO.NET under the covers ....

Comment: Yes But I want to use entity framework as I will use it for my other tables also.